# Image_picker, how to use ImageSource Camera and Gallery in one function

Tags: flutter

I have implemented the possibility to take picture but what I want is to offer the user both options just like in other apps (e.g. WhatsApp) where you can choice between the Camera or Gallery.
I looked on the Image_picker documentation but didn't find anything. Am I missing something or there is no way to achieve it with this plugin?

Comment: if you have found the answer pls share it sir

Comment: no, at the moment I have it this way one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I supposed you can create multiple different widgets (buttons) that access the different source of images? Not sure if it's the best way though.

```
Future getImage(ImageSource imageSource) async {
    // ImageSource.camera or ImageSource.gallery
    File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: imageSource);
    return image;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that’s not what I’m asking for.